# Suspend Mode on Pop OS not working

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, power-management, nvidia, pop-os

I installed the latest version of PopOS on my gaming PC.
If I click on "suspend", everything is shutting down except the PC itself. Any ideas what is wrong and how to address it?
My PC uses Nvidia Geforce 3060 RTX with proprietary drivers.

Here is the relevant journalctl log, can you spot something or do you have some ideas?

```
Dec 18 10:43:59 pop-os ModemManager[832]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Dec 18 10:43:59 pop-os NetworkManager[734]: <info>  [1702892639.6492] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Dec 18 10:43:59 pop-os NetworkManager[734]: <info>  [1702892639.6493] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Dec 18 10:43:59 pop-os gnome-shell[3457]: Timelines with detached actors are not supported. <unnamed>[<Gjs_ui_panel_AggregateMenu>:0x5671b48f5760] in animation of duration 150ms but not on stage.
Dec 18 10:43:59 pop-os gnome-shell[3457]: [popx11gestures@system76.com] Extension disabled
Dec 18 10:43:59 pop-os gnome-shell[3457]: [popx11gestures@system76.com] Building entry point for GNOME Shell 42.5
Dec 18 10:43:59 pop-os gnome-shell[3457]: [popx11gestures@system76.com] No tracker, skipping
Dec 18 10:43:59 pop-os gnome-shell[3457]: [VERTICAL-OVERVIEW] resetting overrides
Dec 18 10:43:59 pop-os gnome-shell[3457]: [VERTICAL-OVERVIEW] disabled
Dec 18 10:43:59 pop-os gnome-shell[3457]: [popx11gestures@system76.com] Connection with Touchégg daemon lost: null
Dec 18 10:43:59 pop-os gnome-shell[3457]: [popx11gestures@system76.com] Connection manually closed, not reconnecting to the daemon
Dec 18 10:44:02 pop-os systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Dec 18 10:44:02 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Dec 18 10:44:02 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Dec 18 10:44:02 pop-os suspend[35194]: nvidia-suspend.service
Dec 18 10:44:02 pop-os logger[35194]: <13>Dec 18 10:44:02 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Dec 18 10:44:02 pop-os systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 18 10:44:02 pop-os systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Dec 18 10:44:02 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Dec 18 10:44:02 pop-os systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 18 10:44:02 pop-os systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "51"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "48"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "53"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) event7  - ROCCAT ROCCAT Kone Aimo 16K Mouse: device removed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "50"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) event9  - ROCCAT ROCCAT Kone Aimo 16K System Control: device removed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "26"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) event11 - ROCCAT ROCCAT Kone Aimo 16K: device removed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "47"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) event2  - Blue Microphones Yeti Nano Consumer Control: device removed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "44"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) event4  - HID 0566:3108: device removed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "24"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "71"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) event6  - HID 0566:3108 System Control: device removed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "52"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) event12 - C-Media Electronics Inc. USB Multimedia Audio Device: device removed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "49"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) event13 - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: device removed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) event8  - ROCCAT ROCCAT Kone Aimo 16K Consumer Control: device removed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "24"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) event5  - HID 0566:3108 Consumer Control: device removed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (**) Option "fd" "80"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) event25 - Creative Stage Air (AVRCP): device removed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:75
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:89
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:77
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:73
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:76
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:71
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:70
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os acpid[736]: client 3351[1000:1000] has disconnected
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os gsd-media-keys[3660]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os gsd-media-keys[3660]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os gsd-media-keys[3660]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os gsd-media-keys[3660]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os gsd-media-keys[3660]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os gsd-media-keys[3660]: Unable to get default source
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx_hd
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_hd
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aac
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aac
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os gsd-media-keys[3660]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os gsd-media-keys[3660]: Unable to get default sink
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os acpid[736]: input device has been disconnected, fd 29
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) config/udev: removing device Creative Stage Air (AVRCP)
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3351]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:89
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_1
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_0
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_1
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_0
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream_duplex
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05_duplex
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os bluetoothd[741]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.220 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os rfkill[35238]: block set for type bluetooth
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os systemd-sleep[35228]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Dec 18 10:44:03 pop-os systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
```

[image]